# Is "Justice of the Peace" an official in the administration of justice in England?

Tags: united-kingdom, constitution, judiciary

Is "Justice of the Peace" an official in the administration of justice in England?

What about the Arbitrators and Juries? Do we consider them officials in the administration of justice?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [magistrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magistrate_%28England_and_Wales%29) may answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the legal system of England and Wales, there is a history of involving lay people, namely people from the local community who are not required to hold any legal qualifications, in the judicial decision-making process of the courts. They are called `Justices of the Peace` or magistrates.

These magistrates were termed "lay magistrates" to distinguish them from professional magistrates known as stipendiary magistrates (now district judges). District judges sit alone to hear cases and are permanently employed by the Ministry of Justice (until May 2007, the Department for Constitutional Affairs). Magistrates are not paid, apart from an allowance for loss of earnings, mileage and subsistence (which are at a standardised rate agreed by the Ministry of Justice).
Source : [Click here for more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magistrate_%28England_and_Wales%29)